# Hexo how to limit post sizes in home page?

Tags: hexo

I was wondering if it's possible to limit the post size on the home page? The current problem that I am facing is if there a long post it does not seems to be truncated. Am I missing a setting in _config.yml or do I have to make a change in the ejs files? This is currently how the [home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r2jQ.png) looks like and this is the [md file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaaOA.png) I am working on. If you can help me it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
<!--more-->
```

In your post (.md) file. Text after the above tag will not display until clicked.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I knew about the <!--more-->, but everytime I was using it was not working. But, for some reason it working now.